# How do I make Elasticsearch fuzzy_like_this treat the like_text tokens as ANDs rather than ORs?

Tags: search, full-text-search, elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

Unlike the "query_string" operator, the "fuzzy_like_this" doesn't have a "default_operator" I can set to "AND", which results in a much larger result set than desired for a multi-term search like "chicken breast".

Is there an alternative way to accomplish this functionality? Like pre-splitting the search tokens and AND'ing a bunch of fuzzy_like_this blocks together? Or preferably something simpler and more intuitive?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/flt-query.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I missed something in your requirements, what you are looking for is [match_query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query.html). It supports AND operator which will require all terms to match the record. Alternatively, you can specify the number or percentage of terms that has to match using `minimum_should_match` parameter.

Comment: yes the match query does have a tunable "fuzziness" variable which appears to provide the necessary functionality. thanks.